# Linked List Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

You're given a linked list 1->2->3->4->5->6->NULL. Why is the output as 1 3 5 5 3 1. I'm very confused, please explain the logic.

```
void fun(struct node *start){
    if(start==NULL){
        return;
    }
    printf("%d",start->data);
    if(start->next!=NULL)
        fun(start->next->next);
    print("%d",start->data);
}
```

Comment: Is it clear why it is printing only odd numbers? If yes, next question. Can you write a recursive function which will print elements in order? Can you write one that prints them in reversed order? Now combine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it in the pseudocode, if you execute it "in your head".

```
fun([1,2,3,4,5,6,NULL])=> //Call fun with list
print(1) //Print 1
fun([3,4,5,6,NULL])=>
print(3)
fun([5,6,NULL])=>
print(5)
fun([NULL])=>
<Do nothing as its next element is equals NULL>
return from fun
print(5)
return from fun
print(3)
return from fun
print(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function is incorrect. It can invoke undefined behavior when the number of nodes is not even. Because in this expression

```
start->next->next
```

the sub-expression

```
start->next
```

can be already equal to `NULL`.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void fun( const struct node *start )
{
    if ( start )
    {
        printf( "%d ",start->data );
        
        if ( start->next && start->next->next ) 
        {
            fun( start->next->next );    
        }
        
        printf( "%d ",start->data );
    }
}
```

Or the following way

```
void fun( const struct node *start )
{
    if ( start )
    {
        printf( "%d ",start->data );
        
        if ( start->next ) 
        {
            fun( start->next->next );    
        }
        
        printf( "%d ",start->data );
    }
}
```

If to comment the if statement then the function two times calls the function `printf` for the same node

```
void fun( const struct node *start )
{
    if ( start )
    {
        printf( "%d ",start->data );

        /*            
        if ( start->next && start->next->next ) 
        {
            fun(start->next->next);    
        }
        */

        printf( "%d ",start->data );
    }
}
```

So at the first call it outputs

```
1 1
```

But if to uncomment the if statement then between the first and the second call of `printf` the function calls itself with a pointer to the next->next node.

So you can write

```
1 3 3 1
```

And so on

```
1 3 5 5 3 1
     ^
     |
```

After the node with the value `5` the pointer to the next-next node is equal to NULL. So between these two calls of printf

```
printf( "%d ",start->data );
//...
printf( "%d ",start->data );
```

within the function when start->data is equal to `5` nothing will be outputted.